# java class with different parameters as parameter of method

Tags: java

I have quite untypical question. In my app I have the following code:

```
public TaskListDatabases getTaskListDatabases (int mode) {
    switch (mode) {
        case (MODE_NORMAL): 
            if (taskListDatabases == null) {
                taskListDatabases = new TaskListDatabases(app); // 1st place
            }
            break;
        case (MODE_FORCE_RERUN): 
            if (taskListDatabases == null) {
                taskListDatabases = new TaskListDatabases(app); // 2nd place
            } else {
                if (taskListDatabases.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
                    taskListDatabases = new TaskListDatabases(app); // 3rd place
            }
            break;
    }
    return taskListDatabases;
}
```

Now I would like to create 4 other functions similar to the one above but differing in the actual object construction place (marked with a comment).

In 1st instead of `new TaskListDatabases(app)` I would like to have `new Task (app, int, int)`, in the 2nd `new Task (app, String, int)`, in the 3rd `new Task (app, String, String, String)`....

All the rest would be the same. I'm wondering if there is any chance to create one function taking as "parameter" the part `new TaskListDatabases(app)`. If it was only the question of class, it wouldn't be the problem as I would have "Class param". However here each class has also different constructor parameters.

Any idea?

Comment: Google for the "Factory" pattern.

Comment: Why not take an instance of a TaskListDatabases as a param?

Comment: Have a look at these [[1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ub0DXaeV6hA)] [[2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbjAsdAK4xQ)]

Comment: @Mash, no way, as I want to control object creation, in some situations I want to create a new object and in some to use previously created.

Comment: @Mr D @ Dirk I don't think it's factory pattern. At least it's not a typical pattern. Perhaps I didn't write it enough clearly. Ex. If I want to use "new Task (Application app, Param1 int, Param2 int)" my main method would look in the following way "public TaskListDatabases getTaskListDatabases (int mode, Param1 int, param2 int). Thus I want to pass different parameters to getTaskListDatabases depending which object I create. And thus in my opinion makes that it's not factory pattern as here we admit that from the point of view of factory there is only one method with the same parameters.

Comment: @user2707175 You can simply pass all of the required parameters and ignore the ones you don't need. Or you might aswell overload the method since you only want three variations.

Comment: Is `TaskListDatabases` a subclass/implementation of `Task`?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory) implemented as an [anonymous](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) behind a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). Confused? Hopefully won't be after this:

Define an interface for the anonymous callbacks:

```
private interface TaskFactory {
    Task create();
}
```

Refactor the base method to use a factory

```
private Task getTask (int mode, TaskFactory factory) {
    switch (mode) {
        case MODE_NORMAL: 
            if (taskListDatabases == null) {
                taskListDatabases = factory.create();
            }
            break;
        case (MODE_FORCE_RERUN): 
            if (taskListDatabases == null) {
                taskListDatabases = factory.create();
            } else {
                if (taskListDatabases.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
                    taskListDatabases = factory.create();
            }
            break;
    }
    return taskListDatabases;
}
```

Then create facade methods for each purpose:

```
public Task getTaskListDatabases(int mode) {
    return getTask(mode,
        new TaskFactory() {
            Task create() {
                return new TaskListDatabases(app);
            }
        }
    }
}

public Task getTaskOther(int mode) {
    return getTask(mode,
        new TaskFactory() {
            Task create() {
                return new Task(app, "foo", 7; // eg
            }
        }
    }
}

// etc for other Task flavours
```

Comment: It seems to be quite complicated. I have to analyse that. But in my case public Task getTaskOther method would have more parameters ex. (int, String, String) which would be transfered to new Task constructor. Not sure how it will influence on AbstractFactory.

Comment: Google "value object" and use one of those with some fields set to null for simpler cases